# A regex must find words that contains a digit. If word symbols include $@, it does not work anymore

Tags: regex

I have tried:

```
\b[\w\@$]*[\d]+[\w\@$]*\b
```

But it does not match `$1$` or `@1@`. But does take `a1a` or `_1_`. Why?

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/iGJt8c/5) is the test

It is not a duplicate, for all existing questions are about a word, containing a digit, but without adding @$ to word symbols. And right here is the strangeness.

Comment: `\b` is based on `\w` pattern. Regex101 shows this explanation for `\b`: *`\b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`*. A `\w` matches letters, digits and `_` (in general). `@` and `$` are symbols, and are not "word" chars. What is your definition of a "word"? Is it for Java or Android, or any other language? Are you extracting or replacing?

Comment: Try [`(?<![\w@$])[\w@$]*\d[\w@$]*(?![\w@$])`](https://regex101.com/r/2j6crT/1) if the regex engine supports all lookarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I share a solution, please see how nicely [your regex matches `1$1$1`](https://regex101.com/r/6arqbM/1). The reason there is a match is that `\b[\w\@$]*[\d]+[\w\@$]*\b` requires a [**word boundary**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), then 0 or more word or `@` or `$` chars, and the trailing part matches 0+ word/`$`/`@` chars followed again with a word boundary.

See regex101 explanation for `\b`: **`\b` assert position at a word boundary (`^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W`)**. That means that to match `\b@` or `\b\$` there must be a word char before `@` or `$`. And to match `@\b` or `\$\b` there must be a word char after `$` / `@`.

Now, what you need is a *custom* word boundary, and this is usually achieved with lookarounds.

```
(?<![\w@$])[\w@$]*\d[\w@$]*(?![\w@$])
^^^^^^^^^^^                ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2j6crT/1).

The `(?<![\w@$])` is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a word / `@` / `$` char immediately to the left of the current location and `(?![\w@$])` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a word / `@` / `$` char immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Thank you so much, Wiktor. It was only for my better understanding of regex - I have played changing task a little and had found that strange (for me) situation. I had decided to know regex better and as a result, the only knowledge that I have improved is that now I am much more sure that I don't know it, except some most primitive details  ... Please, check the second and third sentences in the second peragraph - it seems to me that you have missed two words "non" there.

Comment: @Gangnus I did not miss `non` there. `\b@` will match `a@` because there is a word boundary between `a` and `@` as `a` is a word char and `@` is not. `\b@` will not match `!@` because there is no word boundary between `!` and `@` both being non-word chars.

Comment: Yes, I have misunderstood it, sorry